# Is $\mu_X\otimes \mu_Y(A\times B)=\int_A \mu_Y(B^x)\mu_X(dx)$ hold if $X$ and $Y$ are not independents random variables?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space. I know that if $X$ and $Y$ are two independent r.v., then $$\mu(A\times B):=\mathbb P\{X\in A, Y\in B\}=\mu_X\otimes \mu_Y(A\times B)=\mu_X(A)\mu_Y(B)$$ is a product measure on $\mathbb R^2$. And moreover
$$\mu(A\times  B)=\int_{A}\mu_Y(B^x)\mu_X(dx)=\int_{B}\mu_X(A^y)\mu_Y(dy),$$
where $A^y=\{x\mid (x,y)\in A\times B\}$ and $B^x=\{y\mid (x,y)\in A\times B\}$

**Question :** Now, suppose $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. The measure $\mu_X\otimes\mu_Y$ is a measure on $\mathbb R^2$ but is not a product measure, i.e. $\mu_X\otimes\mu_Y(A\times B)=\mu_X(A)\mu_Y(B)$ doesn't hold anymore. But, does the formula $$\mu_X\otimes \mu_Y(A\times  B)=\int_{A}\mu_Y(B^x)\mu_X(dx)=\int_{B}\mu_X(A^y)\mu_Y(dy)$$
still hold ? I'm a bit in truble since on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_measure) they elaborate this formula for $\mu_X\otimes \mu_Y$ being the product measure (i.e. $\mu_X\otimes\mu_Y(A\times B)=\mu_X(A)\mu_Y(B)$), but it looks that in proposition 3.1 page 278 of "Real-Analysis" of Stein and Shakarchi they make the proof of this formula, but they don't look to use this property. So is this formula still true ?

Comment: I have never seen a reference which uses $\mu_X \otimes \mu_Y$ for something other than the product measure. You may simply introduce a symbol for the joint probability measure, such as $\mu_{X,Y}(A) = \mathbb{P}[(X,Y)\in A]$. And as for your question, notice that $\{y : (x,y)\in A\times B\}$ is either $B$ if $x\in A$ or $\varnothing$ otherwise, and so, we simply have $$\int_{A}\mu_Y(B^x)\,\mu_X(\mathrm{d}x) = \mu_X(A)\mu_Y(B). $$ So asserting that some measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ satisfies $\mu(A\times B)=\int_{A}\mu_Y(B^x)\,\mu_X(\mathrm{d}x)$ simply means $\mu$ is a product measure.

Comment: I mean, if $X$ and $Y$ are not independant, $\mu(A\times B)=\mathbb P\{X\in A,Y\in B\}$ is a measure on $\mathbb R^2$, but it's not the production measure. In this case, does $\mu(A\times B)=\int_A \mu_Y(B^x)\mu_X(dx)$ hold ? @SangchulLee

Comment: As I mentioned, the latter equality should imply that $\mu$ is a product measure. In general, we have a result called [*disintegration theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disintegration_theorem). This theorem tells that there exists a 'nice' family of probability measures $\{\mu_{Y|X}(\cdot|x):x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ such that $$\mu(A\times B)=\int_{A}\mu_{Y|X}(B^x|x)\,\mu_X(\mathrm{d}x).$$ (Note: This formulation is slightly different from that of the link.) You may regard this as measure-theoretic version of conditional probabilities.

Comment: thank you very much. Can we say that $\mu=\mu_{Y|X}(\cdot |x)\otimes \mu_X$ or not really ? (Well it's not very clear with the $x$ in $\mu_{Y\mid X}(\cdot ,x)$ but is there such an idea ?@SangchulLee

Comment: Not really. If you feel confused about this, try with a very specific case: If $\mu$ is absolutely continuous so that $$\mu(\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y)=f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$$ for some density function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$, then independence of $X$ and $Y$ meand that $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$ for some density functions $g$ and $h$ on $\mathbb{R}$, so that $\mu_X(\mathrm{d}x)=g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ and $\mu_Y(\mathrm{d}y)=h(y)\,\mathrm{d}y$. In general, $$\mu_{Y|X}(\mathrm{d}y|x)=\frac{f(x,y)}{\int_\mathbb{R} f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y}\,\mathrm{d}y$$ provided $\int_\mathbb{R} f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y\neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's clear now :)